# Powershell and SFTP.exe

Tags: powershell, sftp

Is it possible to pipe the contents of a folder on an SFTP site to a local file similar to window sinnate ftp.exe program where the syntax:

dir /MainDir/SubDir c:\test\ftp\CurrentContents.txt

but the same syntax does not work with SFTP.exe.   I need to be able to process one file name at a time in a powershell script and I can see no way to pass file names from the SFTP.exe program to the powershell script and back without being able to parse a text file with directory contents.

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions please let me know.
thanks
rp

Answer (score 1):

I use [Rebex's .NET components](http://www.rebex.net/sftp.net/) for FTPS & SFTP in my C# programs & PowerShell scripts. I find it much easier than slinging around external programs that weren't really designed to interact smoothly with scripts & other applications.

Edit: Since money is an issue, have you tried using one of the utilities [bundled with PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)?

Comment: I appreciate the answer but, as a public agency with no funds for additional software, a 350$ price tag is out of league.

Comment: At $20/hour (to make the math easy), if you spend 2 days fighting with `sftp.exe` and haven't gotten it to work yet, you've already spent about $350 of the agency's funds and still don't have a solution.  I understand what you're saying, but time *does* have a dollar value attached to it. See my edit for another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The Push-FTP function from [PowerShell Pipeworks](http://powershellpipeworks.com) does this, but not as perfectly as I would like.  I will make the required edits to support seamless pipelining in a few days.  It also provides a progress bar during uploads.

Here's an example:

```
Push-Ftp -Path c:\Example -Include *.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [putty psftp](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) which works great with powershell.

Usage:

let's create *$tempContentFile* containing ftp commands in **ASCII** encoding

```
$tempContentFile = "$($workdir)\temp_get.txt"
$tempContent = "get -r /root/home/someuser/filestoDownload C:\temp\DownloadedFiles"
$out = out-file -filepath $tempContentFile -inputobject $tempContent -encoding ASCII;
```

First we need to ensure that remote server SSL certificate is accepted/storred locally

```
$out = echo Y|.\plink.exe -v -ssh $($attribute_IP) -l $($attribute_user) -pw $($attribute_password) -batch exit 2>&1
```

Than psftp command itself:

```
$out = .\psftp.exe $($attribute_IP) -l $($attribute_user) -pw $($attribute_password) -b $tempContentFile
```